# Get the C++ member function and the corresponding offset via LLVM IR

Tags: c++, llvm

I would like to have an overall analysis for c++ classes, and I want to know each member function's offset. Could anyone give me any hint on how to get those information in LLVM IR? I would appreciate any help from you.

A code example could be:

```cpp
class Circle {
    int radius;
public:
    void setRadius(int _radius){radius = _radius;}
    int getRadius() {return radius;}
};
```

I would like to know that 1st field is an integer, the 2nd and 3rd field is a member function, and also the definition of the member function.

Comment: Member functions are not located with offsets from objects. They have const absolute addresses equal for all objects like static member variables.

Comment: C++ classes do not have "fields".  You seem to be asking how to inspect (at runtime) what the source code _looks like_.  In general, C++ does not provide ways to know what the original code looks like, because that's not necessary for the code to work.

Comment: Many member functions have an offset within the vtbl. Is that what you're asking about? If so, the answer will be specfic to a single C++ compiler, not general to LLVM. You'll have to read that compiler's code to find out.

Answer (score 2):

There's not really such a thing as a "member function's offset". Functions can be totally optimized away as is the case [here](https://godbolt.org/z/KPfP3E96e). You can take a look at the IR [here](https://godbolt.org/z/MqroerPd4) and it's essentially the same thing. Virtual functions will have an offset into a vtable, but that's another matter.

You can force there to be an address by taking a pointer to a function. You could then calculate an "offset", but relative to what exactly? Not sure there's any guarantee from LLVM how member functions are placed in the text segment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the offset indeed cannot be retrieved in IR level. Currently I add the member function name in the annotation format to those member function, and this could also help to identify the member function instead of offset.